# Why will shell script not execute from Java Runtime.exec but will from command line?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

hope someone can help me here. Googled til my eyes bled and no luck, and tried everything I can think of.

I'm trying to execute a shell script which plays a song. When I type the following into the command line, everything's fine:
 `/home/pi/startsong.sh /path/to/track`

However, I'm trying to execute the script via a Java app, but get no response at all. Here's what I'm doing:

```
public void begin(String song) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //Split song title
    String[] cmd = song.split("");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //Ignore for now, this is just about sorting out titles with spaces, but irrelevant
    for (int i = 0; i < cmd.length; i++) {
        if (cmd[i].equals(" ")) {
            cmd[i] = " ";
        }
        sb.append(cmd[i]);
    }

    //Initiate bash script whilst passing song title as argument
    String command = "/home/pi/startsong.sh " + sb.toString();
    System.out.println(command);
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = rt.exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Playing song...");

}
```

When I run the program, the command it prints (as I ask it to) comes out exactly the same as what I would enter into the command line.

Why doesn't the script execute?

I have tried using `ProcessBuilder` and calling the program that plays the track directly but neither work. For simplicity I'm testing this with a track whose path has no spaces or strange characters.

I have tried adding `/bin/bash -c` to the beginning of the `command` string

FYI I'm running Java 8 on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. The program that plays the track is omxplayer.

Any help most gratefully received as I've been doing my nut in all day with this!

Thanks!

Comment: You can run that correctly on the same hardware and as the same user as you are trying to run the java app on/as?

Comment: Have tried running app and shell script as sudo, no change :/

Comment: That doesn't directly answer the question. Have you tried that script manually as the same user and on the same hw as the java app? Did it work when you tried that? Does the script output any errors/etc. when you run it from java?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question. Yes, the script runs when I run it as the same user and hw as Java app. For clarity, I code in Netbeans but test and run in place on the RPi, so execution is always with the same user and hw. Apologies.

Comment: And no, there are no errors, no nothing in fact. The Java program continues as if it had completed the exec with no difficulties

Comment: Are you actually trying to read the output from the shell script execution? I'm not a java person but I don't see anything that would indicate you are in that snippet? I'm *not* talking about a java error but an error output from the script (on standard output).

Comment: No, I'm not, I'm afraid I'm unused to shell scripts - the only reason I'm using one is because calling the audio player directly also does not work! It is this that makes me suspect the issue is with the java, not the script, although if you could explain to me how to check for error output from the scrip itself, maybe I can confirm/refute this?#

Comment: However, you have lead me to the correct answer. I found a way to get errors from the bash script by adding in an InputStream reader. This told me that the filenames were not being passed correctly. Many thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to @Etan I have managed to solve this. Modified the code thusly, using an InputStream reader to identify problems with filenames:

```
public void begin(String song) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //Split song title
    String[] cmd = song.split("");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //Ignore for now
    for (int i = 0; i < cmd.length; i++) {
        if (cmd[i].equals(" ")) {
            cmd[i] = " ";
        }
        sb.append(cmd[i]);
    }

    //Initiate bash script whilst passing song title as argument

    System.out.println("Playing song...");

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/home/pi/startsong.sh", "/home"+sb.toString());
    final Process process = pb.start();

    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("Program terminated!");

}
```